# Line integral of point charge.

Tags: integration, electromagnetism

This question is motivated by a calculation in Section 2.2.4 of Griffiths' book on an *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, in which he shows that the field of a point charge is curl-free.

The field of a point charge at the origin is given in spherical coordinates by $$\mathbf{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2}\ \hat{\mathbf{r}}.$$

Here $\epsilon_0$ is the permittivity of free space, $q$ is the magnitude of the charge, $r$ is the radius from the origin, and $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ is radial spherical basis vector.

The line integral of interest is $$\int_{\mathbf{a}}^{\mathbf{b}}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{l},$$ and is taken over an arbitrary path in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (that presumably doesn't include the origin).  This integral is calculated in spherical coordinates, so the infinitesimal displacement is given by $$d\mathbf{l}=dr\ \hat{\mathbf{r}}+r\ d\theta\ \hat{\boldsymbol\theta}+r\ \sin\theta\ d\phi\ \hat{\boldsymbol\phi}.$$

In Griffiths' notation $\theta$ is the azimuthal angle, and $\phi$ is the polar angle.  To calculate the integral he first observes $$\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{l}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2}\ dr.$$  The integral is then evaluated as follows $$\int_\mathbf{a}^\mathbf{b}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{l}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_\mathbf{a}^\mathbf{b}\frac{q}{r^2}\ dr=\frac{-1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r}\bigg|^{r_b}_{r_a}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\bigg(\frac{q}{r_a}-\frac{q}{r_b}\bigg).$$
Here $r_a$ and $r_b$ are the radii associated with $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$.  It is then argued that the integral around any closed path is zero, so that $\mathbf{E}$ is curl-free by Stokes theorem.  **I cannot understand how he got from** $$\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_\mathbf{a}^\mathbf{b}\frac{q}{r^2}\ dr$$ **to** $$\frac{-1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r}\bigg|^{r_b}_{r_a}.$$  Doesn't this integral need to be parameterized?  If he is integrating over a contour, how is it legitimate to just take the antiderivative?  I would think that if he is integrating over a path, he would need to express $r=r(\theta,\phi)$ and find a corresponding formula for $dr$.

I am obviously missing something, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.  I would be grateful to anyone who would be able to help.

---

**Edit**: I asking how he got from $\int_\mathbf{a}^\mathbf{b}\frac{1}{\mathbf{r}^2(x)}d(\mathbf{x})$ to $\int_{r(\mathbf{a})}^{r(\mathbf{b})}\frac{1}{r^2}dr$.  Thanks to @Alex Burdin for the suggestion.

Comment: Since $\mathbf{E}$ is curl-free, the integral is path-independent.

Comment: That is absolutely true, but Griffiths is using this calculation to show $\mathbf{E}$ is curl-free.  So it seems as though this reasoning is a bit circular.

Answer (score 0):

$$\vec{E}=E_r\vec{r}+0\vec{\theta}+0\vec{\phi}$$
thus

$$\vec{E}.\vec{dl}=E_rdr=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{dr}{r^2}$$
with
$$\int_{r_a}^{r_b}\frac{1}{r^2}dr=\Bigl[\frac{-1}{r}\Bigr]_{r_a}^{r_b}$$

$$-\frac{1}{r_b}-(-\frac{1}{r_a})=\frac{1}{r_a}-\frac{1}{r_b}$$

Comment: The question was how to get from $\int\limits_{\mathbf{a}}^{\mathbf{b}} \frac{1}{r(\mathbf{x})^2} dr(\mathbf{x})$ to $\int\limits_{r(\mathbf{a})}^{r(\mathbf{b})} \frac{1}{r^2}dr$

Comment: Thanks for chiming in hamam_Abdallah, but that doesn't answer my question.  I understand the trivial antiderivative calculation, but I what I cannot understand is how this calculation is valid in the first place.  Since he is integrating over a path, it seems like he needs to parameterize $r$ as a function of $\theta$ and $\phi$.  This could substantially complicate the integral.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me clarify Alexy Burdin.

Comment: @jackrodgers1554 I think you shuold edit your question to reflect this

Comment: @jackrodgers1554 That will be true if $E=E_r.+E_{\theta}+E_{\phi}$ but in your case E is radial.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Yes $\mathbf{E}$ is radial, but the path over which he is integrating might not be.  Unless the path is one of constant $\theta$ and $\phi$, then we will have $r=r(\theta,\phi)$.  This relation may be implicit.

Comment: @jackrodgers1554 You integrate the scalar product $\vec{E}.\vec{dl}$ which depend only on $r$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Right, but if $r=r(\phi,\theta)$ then $dr=dr(\phi,\theta)$, and the integration is more complicated.